# How do I order by the number of repetitions, then by date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following SQL query.

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`data`, p.`title`, p.`creation_date`, t.`name` AS 'tag'

    FROM `post_tag` pt, `post` p, `tag` t 

    WHERE p.`id` = pt.`post` 
        AND pt.`tag` = t.`id` 
        AND p.`author` <> '1'
        AND (t.`name` = 'Programming' 
            OR t.`name` = 'Photography' 
            OR t.`name` = '[...]') 

    ORDER BY p.`creation_date`, t.`name` DESC
```

And my resulting table looks like this:

[image: sql result]

As I've highlighted in the screenshot, rows with ID 76 and 77 are repeated. In my application's case, that is a measure of "popularity". I want to be able to:

1. Group rows where "data" is repeated into one row (I know I can do this with GROUP BY)
2. Order the rows by "popularity" first, then by "creation_date". So, if there are 3 rows with the same "data", the I want that to be returned first, followed by rows with a count of 2, etc.

Comment: `GROUP BY data ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC, p.creation_date, t.name DESC` should work

Comment: what do you mean by order by creation_date, since popular data will have more than one?  you can order by min(p.creation_date) or max(p.creation_date).

Comment: @ysth good point! I think ordering by MIN(p.creation_date) would be better in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... group by p.data order by count(*) desc, p.creation_date, t.name desc
```

Comment: You may want to use `MIN(p.creation_date)` to get a deterministic date to order by in case each url has a separate timestamp.

Comment: Thanks so much to the both of you. I can accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: `count(*)` is the number of rows in each group. `count(expression)` is the number of rows in each group where `expression` is not `null`.